# Update a value in remote database if app is killed or closed while in background

Tags: android, kill, ondestroy

I need to set my `boolean` `isOnline` to false and update it in remote database if app is closed or killed.

Is there a way to detect if my user do this  ?

I don't want to do this in `onStop()`. And `onDestroy()` doesn't seem to get called if my user kill app process through Android.

Regards,

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStop()

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm may I ask why you don't want to do this in `onStop`?

Anyway, `onStop` may not always be called in low-memory situations, as well as `onDestroy`, such as when Android is starved for resources and cannot properly background the Activity.

So, `onPause` is the last method you are guaranteed will be called.
And maybe you can use it in combination with `isFinishing()`, as explained in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isFinishing%28%29

> `public boolean isFinishing ()`
>
> Check to see whether this activity is in the process of finishing,
>   either because you called finish() on it or someone else has requested
>   that it finished. This is often used in onPause() to determine whether
>   the activity is simply pausing or completely finishing.

Another method that could be of your interest if you are exploring alternatives:

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus)
```

Called when the current Window of the activity gains or loses focus. This is the best indicator of whether this activity is visible to the user. The default implementation clears the key tracking state, so should always be called.

(going to background does not have to mean the user closed the app, but you'll know if it could be of use for you)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, isFinishing is useful. But it doesn't really solve my issue. I want to set the boolean to false if my user kill app from the OS, when the app has already been reduced (put in background). And i think only onDestroy is called in this case...

Answer (score 0):

Well, then I can only think you should start a service aside (in its own process) to check if your app is killed by reading the list of application processes that are running on the device with `getRunningAppProcesses()` See [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningAppProcesses()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningAppProcesses%28%29)